# Blazor EditForm validation only partially works when using a 'Validator component' (within a 'business logic validation' function)

Tags: c#, validation, razor, blazor

The issue is I'm not able to get a validation message to show against a field. Although the error message does appear in the validation summary.

[screenshot showing what I would like to see happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJ0n.png)

This issue is also further restricted to only complex model properties. The approach of using "ValidateComplexType", "ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator" to resolve complex model property validation limitation does not help in this instance.

The sample code below which I have created to demonstrate the problem is virtually ALL code from the Microsoft docs website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation).

> Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
<h1>Starfleet Starship Database</h1>

<h2>New Ship Entry Form</h2>

<EditForm Model="@starship" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidator @ref="customValidator" />
    <ValidationSummary />
    @*<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />*@     @* does not work!*@
    <p>
        <label>
            Identifier:
            <InputText @bind-Value="starship.Identifier" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.Identifier)" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Description (optional):
            <InputTextArea @bind-Value="starship.Description" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.Description)" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Primary Classification:
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="starship.Classification" disabled="@disabled">
                <option value="">Select classification ...</option>
                <option value="Exploration">Exploration</option>
                <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
                <option value="Defense">Defense</option>
            </InputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.Classification)" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Maximum Accommodation:
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="starship.MaximumAccommodation" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.MaximumAccommodation)" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Engineering Approval:
            <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="starship.IsValidatedDesign" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.IsValidatedDesign)" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Production Date:
            <InputDate @bind-Value="starship.ProductionDate" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.ProductionDate)" />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>Captain's Name</strong>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            Firstname:
            <InputText @bind-Value="starship.CaptainsName.Firstname" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.CaptainsName.Firstname)" />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            Lastname:
            <InputText @bind-Value="starship.CaptainsName.Lastname" disabled="@disabled" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => starship.CaptainsName.Lastname)" />
        </label>
    </p>

    <button type="submit" disabled="@disabled">Submit</button>

    <p style="@messageStyles">
        @message
    </p>

    <p>
        <a href="http://www.startrek.com/">Star Trek</a>,
        &copy;1966-2019 CBS Studios, Inc. and
        <a href="https://www.paramount.com">Paramount Pictures</a>
    </p>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private bool disabled;
    private string message;
    private string messageStyles = "visibility:hidden";
    private CustomValidator customValidator;
    private Starship starship = new Starship() { ProductionDate = DateTime.UtcNow };


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        customValidator = new CustomValidator();

        starship = new Starship()
        {
            ProductionDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Identifier = "1",
            Classification = "Defense",
            MaximumAccommodation = 100,
            IsValidatedDesign = true,
            CaptainsName = new PersonsName { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Kirk" }
        };
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {
        bool isValid = editContext.Validate(); // Data Annotations validation

        if (isValid)
        {
            BusinessLogicValidation();
        }
    }

    private bool BusinessLogicValidation()
    {
        customValidator.ClearErrors();

        var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        if (starship.Classification == "Defense" &&
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(starship.Description))
        {
            errors.Add(nameof(starship.Description),
                new List<string>() { "For a 'Defense' ship classification, 'Description' is required." });
        }

        if (starship.CaptainsName.Firstname != "James")
        {
            //errors.Add(nameof(starship.CaptainsName.Firstname), new List<string>() { "Firstname must be James" });  // does not work (as expected)!
            errors.Add("CaptainsName.Firstname", new List<string>() { "Firstname must be James" });
        }


        if (errors.Count() > 0)
        {
            customValidator.DisplayErrors(errors);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Starship.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlazorTest1.Client.Shared
{
    public class Starship
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Identifier too long (16 character limit).")]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Classification { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Accommodation invalid (1-100000).")]
        public int MaximumAccommodation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "This form disallows unapproved ships.")]
        public bool IsValidatedDesign { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }


        // [ValidateComplexType]      // does not work!
        public PersonsName CaptainsName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> PersonsName.cs

```
namespace BlazorTest1.Client.Shared
{
    public class PersonsName
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> CustomValidator.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

public class CustomValidator : ComponentBase
{
    private ValidationMessageStore messageStore;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"{nameof(CustomValidator)} requires a cascading " +
                $"parameter of type {nameof(EditContext)}. " +
                $"For example, you can use {nameof(CustomValidator)} " +
                $"inside an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
        }

        messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(CurrentEditContext);

        CurrentEditContext.OnValidationRequested += (s, e) => 
            messageStore.Clear();
        CurrentEditContext.OnFieldChanged += (s, e) => 
            messageStore.Clear(e.FieldIdentifier);
    }

    public void DisplayErrors(Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors)
    {
        foreach (var err in errors)
        {
            messageStore.Add(CurrentEditContext.Field(err.Key), err.Value);
        }

        CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    public void ClearErrors()
    {
        messageStore.Clear();
        CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }
}
```

Any idea why I dont get the validation message against the field?

Comment: ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator work just fine , you only need to add validation to your complex object (PersonsName) example : 
[Required]
public string Firstname { get; set; }

Comment: Hi @yasseros, I'm wanting to use the Validator Component (CustomValidator.cs) to perform this validation, not data annotation. I have inow included it in the question

Comment: @richard have you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the use of reflection to "find" the property names of the objects in the Validation For lambda.  One workaround, would be to add a property to the class that is used as context ...

For example in Class ...

```
public string CaptainsFirstName => CaptainsName.FirstName;
```

And your validation For would then be

```
<ValidationMessage For="() => starship.CaptainsFirstName" />
```

Not a great solution, but it has worked for me.